# Where to find Python 2.7.14 RPM packages for SLES 11

Tags: python, python-2.7, upgrade, rpm, sles

I would like to upgrade the Python on my SLES 11 from 2.6.9 to 2.7.14 version. The environment isn't prepared for development (make is not installed and zipper cannot help). Could you please recommend a way how to get Python 2.7.14 RPM files for SLES 11.

Comment: Even fedora 25 is still on python `2.7.13`. Do you absolutely need `2.7.14`?

Comment: Just in case python `2.7.13` turns out to be ok, you can use [rpmfind](https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=python+2.7&submit=Search+...) to find most packages that are publicly hosted in many flavors.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually, I would like to upgrade up to the latest version but 2.7.13 will work as well. I have found rpm files in Sles 12. Now trying to install those rpms in my Sles 11. Is the rpmfind.net trusted source?

Comment: As trusted as any non-internal repo can get, so it depends on your business restrictions. For development, I would consider it absolutely viable. For production environment it would be better to build from the official python source yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for is a [Software Collection](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/). I just checked and their [Python 2.7](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/python27/) is still at 2.7.13 at this time, but they have instructions on how to build your own.

Do **not** change out the default system-level python (as suggested in some comments)! Bad things can happen and things like `yum` can break.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to upgrade the python on my Sles 11 from 2.6.9 to 2.7.14 version. The environment isn't prepared for development(make is not installed and zipper cannot help). Could you please recommend a way how to get Python 2.7.14 RPM files for Sles 11.

Seems to be Fedora is recommended as Python 2.17.13, but install 2.7.14 step-by-step are at [here](https://tecadmin.net/install-python-2-7-on-centos-rhel/).

Comment: anways cachingfor sime deletetionkk

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a batteries-included distribution, like Anaconda from Continuum (https://continuum.io, https://www.anaconda.com/download/).  The free version has excellent package management.  You would just choose the installer for Python 2.7 (or optionally Python 3.x).  It also installs directly into your home directory, or any other desired location.  It works on systems going back to Redhat 6.